# Alert when URLS changes from Angular 1 pages to Angular 2 pages

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-routing, angular1.6

I have project in which some screens are in angular 1 and some are in angular 2 .When i have some unsaved data and i try to navigate to Angular 2 pages I need to trigger a `alert` or may be a `console.log` . how can i achieve this and also vice versa ?

I have tried `$routeChangeStart` and `$locationChangeStart` these events are not getting fired when I move from Angular 1 pages to Angular 2 pages .They work fine when i navigate from Angular 1 to Angular 1 pages with unsaved data

Any suggestions

Thanks

Comment: what is Angular 1 and Angular 2

Comment: I meant Versions 1.6 and 2

Comment: so in general you call it as Angular and Angualr js

Comment: but specifying the version of angular (2 or 4) is useful as some errors could be version related

Comment: It is on Angular 1.6 and 2 (or Angular and Angular JS)